# Regular expressions in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to match the following expression in notepad ++, how can I do that ? 
`<table align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="3" border="1" bgcolor="#B1A0C7">`

I want to match from the beginning of `<table` and then all in between characters and stop at the first `>`

i did the following but it doesn't work for me 
`(<table).*>$` it keep getting the last `>` in the line ... I want the first `>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table[^>]*?>
```

explain:

> ***`*?`***
>   Matches the previous element zero or more times, but as few times as possible.
>
> ***`[^character_group]`***
>   Negation: Matches any single character that is not in `character_group`.

Comment: What if you have a newline in your `<table>` tag, as is sometimes used to make those more readable, when a lot of properties are added?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<table[^>]*>
```

Use `[^>]` to match any character but `>`, making it select only that first tag. This will include newline characters, so this regex **will** work for:

```
<table align="center"
       cellpadding="4"
       cellspacing="3"
       border="1"
       bgcolor="#B1A0C7">
```

Comment: `<table[^>]*>$` will only match first line matched .. if there is more in the page won't match .. i think

Comment: @osos: I copied the `$` from your attempt, assuming that's what you wanted. Without it (As edited), it will match any table element. Too bad someone else thought it was a good idea to basically copy my answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus: +1 for using `[^>]`